# Validation, callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, callback

I have a custom validation rule on a model that says the user can't have more than 3 records with a state of active.

validate :not_over_active_limit, :before => :create

The issue arises when I need to update one of the user's 3 active records. When I call record.update! or record.save!, a validation error is thrown saying that I can't have more than three active records. But I only want the validation to run on before_create, not on save! or update!

I can get around this by calling save(false), but I don't want to do that.

Any suggestions for handling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you are looking for is

```
 validate :not_over_active_limit, :on => :create
```

Not `:before` but `:on`

Comment: That didn't work. But this did: validate :not_over_active_limit, :on => :create, :if => Proc.new { |r| r.new_record? }

Comment: Thats interesting because the proc you have specified essentially means that you want to validate only on create.